# How do I make a <div> move downward a little until i am satisfied with its position?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move a stubborn Trust pilot image downwards but it has been stuck and refuse to move. HERE IT IS:

```html
         <!-- TRUST PILLOT -->
    <div style="    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;">
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="mt-1_5 scroll-to" style="    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
  
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #1991ff;
    margin-top: 1.5rem !important;"><img src="trustpilot-logo.svg" alt="Trustpilot reviews" width="232" height="23" style="    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: "Nunito Sans",sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #1991ff;
    width: 232px;
    aspect-ratio: auto 232 / 23;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: welcome to SO. may I ask why you have font-size on an `img` tag? also it seems like you have copied some css directly into your html which is messing some stuff up. the `"`for your fonr-family is effectively terminating your `style` attribute and creating a new attribute called `Nunito Sans` after which a string is next. I would suggest cleaning up your css and removing non-essentials...

Comment: thanks JoSSte for your amazing reply. but I am a beginner. how do i make my image come down a bit ? a good direction will do

Answer (score 0):

you need to read some articles about css and layout. I'd recommend starting at [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

I don't have the svg, but I have used the trustpilot logo from wikipedia to illustrate your issue. I have also made it a little more clear what may be going on by adding a border to your `div`, a pink background to your `a`nchor element and a red background to your `img` element.
If you look at the second snippet, there is a `100px` padding pushing the `a`nchor (and the `img`) down, because I added the padding to the top (`padding: 100px 0 0 0` first one is top. [This is CSS shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)). This could also have been done with a `padding-top` element in the css.

Also note that if you move your css to a separate stylesheet your html (and php if you are mixing it all up) becomes easier to read.

### Your original code - solely modified to ease readability

```css
div.divStyle {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div.divStyle a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color:pink;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #1991ff;
    margin-top: 1.5rem !important;
}

div.divStyle a img {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: "Nunito Sans",sans-serif;
    background-color: red;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #1991ff;
    width: 232px;
    aspect-ratio: auto 232 / 23;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
         <!-- TRUST PILLOT -->
<div class="divStyle">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="mt-1_5 scroll-to">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/Trustpilot_Logo_%282022%29.svg" alt="Trustpilot reviews" width="232" height="23" style="">
  </a>
</div>
```

### Padding on anchor element top

```css
div.divStyle {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div.divStyle a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color:pink;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #1991ff;
    margin-top: 1.5rem !important;
}

div.divStyle a img {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: "Nunito Sans",sans-serif;
    background-color: red;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #1991ff;
    width: 232px;
    aspect-ratio: auto 232 / 23;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
         <!-- TRUST PILLOT -->
<div class="divStyle">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="mt-1_5 scroll-to">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/Trustpilot_Logo_%282022%29.svg" alt="Trustpilot reviews" width="232" height="23" style="">
  </a>
</div>
```